# Why do I get nan from a new column consisting of the average of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, python-3.9

I need to create a new column consisting of the average of other columns in the dataframe. If I add the columns to be averaged manually everything works, as in this case:

Case 1 - It works and give me a new column "BL_SFI_AV" with float

```
matrice_clean['BL_SFI_AV'] = matrice_clean[['BL_SFI_01','BL_SFI_02','BL_SFI_03']].mean(axis = 1)
```

Unfortunately, when I want to use the column slice and then give a range of columns to take the result of the new column is nan. I can't figure out where the problem is. Here is the code I use for the slice:

Case 2 - It doesn't give me any error but the new column BL_SFI_AV is full of nan.

```
matrice_clean['BL_SFI_AV'] = matrice_clean.loc['BL_SFI_01':'BL_SFI_03'].mean (axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think your "case 2" example contains an error.  The columns are in the second axis, so you need to include a row indexer first:

```
matrice_clean.loc[:, 'BL_SFI_01':'BL_SFI_03'].mean (axis = 1)
#                 ^^
#                 Don't forget this
```

Next, I have a theory: In what *order* to your columns appear?

If they are not stored as `['BL_SFI_01','BL_SFI_02','BL_SFI_03']`, then using slicing notation `['BL_SFI_01':'BL_SFI_03']` will not have the desired effect.

For example, this works fine:

```
In [25]: cols = ['BL_SFI_01', 'BL_SFI_02', 'BL_SFI_03']
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((5, 3)), columns=cols)
    ...: df.loc[:, 'BL_SFI_01':'BL_SFI_03'].mean(axis=1)
Out[25]:
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
dtype: float64
```

But this returns `NaN`, because the column order is reversed:

```
In [26]: cols = ['BL_SFI_03', 'BL_SFI_02', 'BL_SFI_01']
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((5, 3)), columns=cols)
    ...: df.loc[:, 'BL_SFI_01':'BL_SFI_03'].mean(axis=1)
Out[26]:
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
dtype: float64
```